# How to convert `Result<T,E>` into `Option<T>`, and return None for any error?

Tags: rust

I have a code that try to read a database. The `get_f64` function is a third party function that reads a database and returns `Result<f64,ValueAccessError>` type.

It returns an error if there are no `foo` field inside `my_variable`.
I need to convert it into `Option<f64>` it will return `Some(f64)` if there's a value and None if there's none/null. How to convert `Result<T,E>` into `Option<T>`, and return None for any error?

```
// this returned Result<f64, ValueAccessError>
let value = my_variable.get_f64("foo");

// but I need Option<f64>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Result::ok()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) to convert a `Result` into an `Option`:

```
let value = my_variable.get_f64("foo").ok();
```